Can I correct a zfs data error in an old snapshot without completely recreating the snapshot?
I have an external USB hard drive with a zfs filesystem on it. I use it as insurance against btrfs bugs, by rsyncing one btrfs snapshot off my root disk every month and then snapshotting it. These snapshots go back a few years.
Recently I did something risky with it (possibly powered off without unmounting properly, I forget exactly what happened) and now zpool scrub reports 71 data errors. zpool status -v tells me that these errors are mostly in snapshots, in most cases recent snapshots but in one case in the snapshot 2019-03.
I have the original data for all of these files in my btrfs snapshots, but I would like to avoid having to recreate the last five and a half years of zfs snapshots from there, because in my experience this will take a very long time. Is there any way I can fix that one file in that 2019-03 snapshot, knowing what data it should hold, without having to recreate that snapshot and every snapshot since?
(I am separately testing the disk for hardware faults, so maybe this question will end up not relevant to my current case, but I'd still be curious to know the answer in that case.)

@BenMillwood (this doesn't address the question, more an FYI) If the external drive is a single drive only, ZFS shouldn't be used - ZFS is software RAID and needs at least two drives in the pool or the filesystem is pointless

@JW0914 transparent compression and copy-on-write snapshots don't seem pointless to me

You lose the benefits of ZFS with only a single drive pool - the only reason you're having this issue is because it's a single drive pool =]

@JW0914 I don't lose all the benefits of ZFS, I just named two that I'm still getting. Of course I lose the redundancy benefits if I don't use redundancy, but I keep the other benefits just fine.

The whole point of ZFS is redundancy (it's software RAID) as a self-healing filesystem that uses checksum verification to replace corrupted files from another copy on another disk in the pool. ZFS isn't intended to be used as a single disk pool (also stated in the man pages). The way this issue would be solved under normal circumstances would be to run a resilver on the pool, but a single disk pool makes that impossible. You may be able to find a way to do what you're looking to do but the only way to resolve this from happening in the future is to add a second disk to the pool.

(Cont'd...) If wanting to use a single disk pool, it really should be used only for data that isn't important - for example, I use a SSD as a single disk pool for rsync backup logs on my TrueNAS server since those logs speed up the backup process to my backup pool, however if the pool or the logs ever got corrupted, the worst that occurs is an 8TB backup has to be logged again. Something else to keep in mind is since a ZFS pool is easily corrupted by a sudden power loss (a UPS is a must for ZFS), it's another really important  reason for pools to have a min. of two drives to recover from

@JW0914 as I mentioned in the question, I have redundancy above the filesystem level (as in: I also have these files on other filesystems) so having it at the filesystem level as well seems pretty wasteful. Nevertheless, I'm happy to accept that my use case isn't supported because it's uncommon among zfs users.

It's not so much that it's uncommon (it is, but that's not the main), more so it's not really a supported configuration of ZFS because ZFS is literally software RAID and was designed to have more than one disk/vdev apart of a pool - it was never designed to be used on single disk pools (warnings are often given on an OS when trying to create a single disk pool). Something to consider is you don't need vdevs on the same hardware, so you could use a second external drive, a USB drive, etc as a second vdev to add to the pool (keep in mind it should equal the same size as the existing drive)
